# Is the order of the parameters important in an ASPNET web service with a SOAP 1.0 XML request?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, axis

When we try to call a web service using a java client (Axis) we are sending the method parameters fields in different order.

That is to say, if the WSDL order of the parameters is like;

```
<soap:Body>
    <somemethod>
      <messagetype>
        **<x>int</x>**
        <y>int</y>
      </messagetype>
    </somemethod>
</soap:Body>
```

and if we send them like

```
<soap:Body>
    <somemethod>
      <messagetype>
        **<y>int</y>**
        <x>int</x>
      </messagetype>
    </somemethod>
</soap:Body>
```

parameters are not filled in the ASPNET side. "x" and "y" stays as zeros ("0").

Any ideas if this is the standard?

Comment: While I am certainly not a Java developer by any means, I seem to recall from my ASMX web service work from years ago that the client encoding of parameters needs to match the service encoding. Are you setting any particular encoding for your Java client?

Comment: No, both are UTF-8, but after making the order, it works.

Comment: Do you have the control of the service and/or source code?

Comment: If I only had that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a SOAP request is just XML so my thoughts are that it's the SOAP implementation that would determine how parameters should match up.

But that varies from vendor to vendor. Some vendors may grab SOAP parameter values by element name (the proper way) and others may grab the values by node position (what you're probably running into).

Stick to the format specified by the WSDL and nobody gets hurt.